# ¿Cómo calcular la moda de una lista manualmente en Python?

Tags: python, estadística

tengo una tarea en la que se nos pide calcular la moda de una lista de números, creada por el usuario, si logro obtener la moda si solo hay una moda en los datos que el usuario ingresó, pero si hay dos o más, me sigue diciendo que si hay una moda ocupo que diga que no hay moda. Gracias.

```
variableModa = None
variableCantidad = 0
for index, numero in enumerate (lista) :
    cantidadVecesAparece = lista.count (numero)
    if cantidadVecesAparece > variableCantidad :
        variableCantidad = cantidadVecesAparece
        variableModa = numero
print ("La moda de la lista es el número ", variableModa)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Crea una lista vacia. Cuando encuentres una moda, agregala a la lista. Cuando salgas del `for`, mira cuando elementos tiene la lista. Si tiene uno, es la moda; si tiene dos o más, no hay moda.

Comment: Si la solución no te sirve, puedes poner comentarios a las respuestas y no DEBES aceptar la respuesta hasta que resuelvas tu duda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una solución sencilla, sin ocupar librerías:

```
valores = {valor:lista.count(valor) for valor in set(lista)}
maximo = max(valores.values())
modas = {k:v for k, v  in valores.items() if v == maximo}
```

Veamos paso a paso, usando esta lista como base

```
lista = [3, 7, 5, 13, 20, 23, 39, 23, 40, 23, 14, 12, 56, 23, 29, 29,  29]
```

Primero contamos las ocurrencias de cada valor:

```
valores = {valor:lista.count(valor) for valor in set(lista)}
```

Usamos `set(lista)` para eliminar todos los valores duplicados y una comprensión de diccionarios para obtener un diccionario con llave igual al valor de la lista, y con su contenido igual al número de veces que aparece. Obtenemos este diccionario:

```
{3: 1, 5: 1, 7: 1, 39: 1, 40: 1, 12: 1, 13: 1, 14: 1, 20: 1, 23: 4, 56: 1, 29: 3}
```

Obtenemos luego el máximo número de ocurrencias de un valor:

```
maximo = max(valores.values())
```

Y luego extraemos del diccionario aquellas entrada que son moda, o sea, cuyo valor asociado sea igual al maximo calculado:

```
modas = {k:v for k, v  in valores.items() if v == maximo}
```

Si ese diccionario tiene sólo una entrada, esa es la moda; si tiene más de una, no hay moda:

```
if len(modas) == 1:
    print(f"La moda es {list(modas)[0]}, con {maximo} ocurrencias")
else:
    print("Las modas son: ")
    for k in modas.keys():
        print(f"Moda {k}, con {maximo} ocurrencias")
```

#### Demo

```
lista = [3, 7, 5, 13, 20, 23, 39, 23, 40, 23, 14, 12, 56, 23, 29, 29,  29]

valores = {valor:lista.count(valor) for valor in set(lista)}
maximo = max(valores.values())
modas = {k:v for k, v  in valores.items() if v == maximo}

if len(modas) == 1:
    print(f"La moda es {list(modas)[0]}, con {maximo} ocurrencias")
else:
    print("Las modas son: ")
    for k in modas.keys():
        print(f"Moda {k}, con {maximo} ocurrencias")
```

produce:

```
La moda es 23, con 4 ocurrencias

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Si agregamos un cuarto valor 29 a `lista`

```
lista = [3, 7, 5, 13, 20, 23, 39, 23, 40, 23, 14, 12, 56, 23, 29, 29, 29, 29]
```

obtenemos:

```
Las modas son: 
Moda 23, con 4 ocurrencias
Moda 29, con 4 ocurrencias

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Hay un cometario que me indica que tiene que ser sin librerías. Una posible solución es la siguiente:

```
import numpy as np

array = [2,5,3,4,5,4,3,6,7,8,9,2,3,2,1,2,3,1,1,2,1]
variableModa = None
variableCantidad = 0

array.sort()

repeticiones = []
#Guardamos en un array el numero de repeticiones por numero del array
for index, numero in enumerate (array):
    #Añadimos solamente una vez las veces que se repite un numero
    if(numero != array[index-1] and index != 0):
        cantidadVecesAparece = array.count(array[index-1])
        repeticiones.append(cantidadVecesAparece)

#Añadimos la moda del ultimo valro que no se añade en el for
repeticiones.append(array.count(array[len(array)-1]))

#Comprobamos que solo hay un máxmio. En caso de haber dos números máximos iguales, no hay una sola moda
#Obtenemos el valor que más se repite
moda = np.amax(repeticiones)
#Calculamos cuantas veces se repite el máximo
veces_maximo = repeticiones.count(moda)

#Si se repite más de una vez es que hay dos modas
if(veces_maximo == 1):
    print("La moda vale ", moda)
else:
    print("La moda se repites varias veces")
```

El proceso en general sería crear un array con las veces que se repite cada número y luego contabilizar si hay sólo un máximo o hay varios dentro de ese array. Si quieres sacar luego cual es esa moda, es decir, poder mostrar cual es el valor del número que pertenece a la moda, pues tendrías que crear un array auxiliar con los números del array inicial eliminando repetidos y mostrar el numero del índice de la moda máxima:

```
#Obtenemos el array inicial sin repetidos
array_sin_repes = []
for i in range(0, len(array)):
    if(array[i] not in array_sin_repes):
        array_sin_repes.append(array[i])

##Una vez que tenemos el array sin repes, clculamos la posicion en donde se encuentra el máximo
pos_maximo = np.where(repeticiones == np.amax(repeticiones))
```

Por lo que el código final, sería el siguiente:

```
import numpy as np

array = [2,5,3,4,5,4,3,6,7,8,9,2,3,2,1,2,3,1,1,2,1]
variableModa = None
variableCantidad = 0

array.sort()

repeticiones = []
#Guardamos en un array el numero de repeticiones por numero del array
for index, numero in enumerate (array):
    #Añadimos solamente una vez las veces que se repite un numero
    if(numero != array[index-1] and index != 0):
        cantidadVecesAparece = array.count(array[index-1])
        repeticiones.append(cantidadVecesAparece)

#Añadimos la moda del ultimo valro que no se añade en el for
repeticiones.append(array.count(array[len(array)-1]))

#Comprobamos que solo hay un máxmio. En caso de haber dos números máximos iguales, no hay una sola moda
#Obtenemos el valor que más se repite
moda = np.amax(repeticiones)
#Calculamos cuantas veces se repite el máximo
veces_maximo = repeticiones.count(moda)

#Obtenemos el array inicial sin repetidos
array_sin_repes = []
for i in range(0, len(array)):
    if(array[i] not in array_sin_repes):
        array_sin_repes.append(array[i])

#Una vez que tenemos el array sin repes, clculamos la posicion en donde se encuentra el máximo
pos_maximo = np.where(repeticiones == np.amax(repeticiones))

#Si se repite más de una vez es que hay dos modas
if(veces_maximo == 1):
    print("La moda corresponde al numero ", array_sin_repes[pos_maximo[0][0]], " y tiene el valor de ", moda)
else:
    print("La moda se repites varias veces")
```

Comment: `numpy` es una librería

Comment: Y? No pone que no se pueda utilizar numpy, lo que no se puede utilizar son funciones que te calcule la moda automáticamente. La librería numpy, sólo se utiliza para calcular el máximo, si tampoco de puede es tan simple como hacer un for que te devuelva el máximo y la posición del mismo.

Answer (score 0):

Es tan fácil como usar la función `multimode` que nos ofrece la librería `statistics` de Python.
El código sería el siguiente:

```
from statistics import mode, multimode

array = [1,1,2,2,3,4,5,4,3,6,7,8,9,2,3,2,1,2,3,1,1,2,1]
moda = multimode(array)
if(len(moda) != 1):
    print("No hay solo una moda")
else:
    print("La moda es ", moda)

> No hay solo una moda
```

Espero que te sirva

Comment: Parece que la tarea es sin usar librerías ...